# Probability of getting a pair in Texas Hold'em poker

Tags: probability

I want to know the probability of getting a pair after all 5 cards are dealt on the table and assuming that I haven't got a pocket pair.

Let's assume that I hold an ace and a king and 50 cards are left. So the probability of getting a pair is: `P(getting an ace) + P(getting a king) + P(5 table cards having a pair of anything else than ace or king)`

Then:

$P(pair) = \frac {3}{50} + \frac{3}{50} + \frac{44 \times 3 \times 40 \times 36 \times 32 \times {5 \choose 2}}{50 \times 49 \times 48 \times 47 \times 46} = 0.3592 = 35.92\%$

**Am I thinking correct?**

Comment: Do you want the probability of getting exactly one pair or the probability of getting at least a pair (ignoring the possibility of getting flushes and straights)?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Just the probability of getting 1 pair.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Let me rephrase: do you want to exclude the case where you get AKxxx on the table?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes exclude, because that would be two pairs not 1 pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost. You actually need

```
P(getting exactly one ace, no kings, and no pair) +
P(getting exactly one king, no aces, and no pair) +
P(getting no aces or kings but exactly one pair)
```

The number of combinations for the first is $3 \binom{11}{4} 4^4$ where the $3$ is the number of remaining aces, the $\binom{11}{4}$ accounts for the combinations of possible values for the other cards, and the $4^4$ accounts for their suits. The number of combinations for the second is identical.

For the third, there are 11 possible values for the pair, with $\binom{4}{2}$ possible suit combinations, 10 values left which are neither the pair nor AK, so we have $11 \binom{4}{2} \binom{10}{3} 4^3$.

This gives a final result of $$P(\text{exactly one pair}) = \frac{6\binom{11}{4}4^4 + 11\binom{4}{2}\binom{10}{3}4^3}{\binom{50}{5}}$$

(The numerical result is $\frac{25344}{52969}$ or about 47.85%).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand why suits are to the 4th and 3rd power. The suits shouldn't matter, only the ranks matters.

Comment: Four cards and three cards respectively.

Comment: Does this also account for outcomes such as suit flushes?

Comment: @ChrisKempen, no. Now that I re-read the comments on the question, I think that maybe OP did want to discount flushes and straights, but at the time I must have interpreted it the other way. Although it *does* exclude full house by virtue of excluding two pairs.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - Thank you so much for the response! Agree completely, and in thinking about it again _technically_ a pair could exist within the flush, so perhaps this question should be asked of the OP. In any event, thank you again, your answer helped me so much in my own calculations.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just wrote a program to compute basic poker probabilities, and empirically (off of a million hands), there is about a 44% chance of getting a pair. However, this doesn't count pairs being in straights or in flushes (so A A K Q J 10 9 8 is not counted), which should account for the discrepancy